# find blank character in c++

Tags: c++, char, find

I wanted to see the following code in the C ++ language can find the first blank character in the string or empty space on the top of the string.

```
for(;*str == ' '; str++)
```

Comment: Whats the question?  You want to march down a string till the first blank character?

Comment: That would at least be `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Use `std::find` or `std::find_if`, or possibly a member function on `std::string`

Comment: Don't invalidate the answers you get.

Comment: **Note:** both examples below work and do basically the same thing.  One is more brought out while the other is compact and uses the fundamentals of a `char*`

Answer (score 4):

This code will not find the first blank in a string. Instead, it will run an infinite loop, eventually causing a crash due to undefined behavior.

What you are looking for is something that continues until `*str` is not a null terminator or blank:

```
for ( ; *str && *str != ' ' ; str++)
    ; // The body of the loop is empty
```

**Note:** This code is for learning exercise to understand how C strings work. In C++ code you would use `std::string` instead, with member functions that provide this functionality without you having to write any additional code.

Comment: His code wont run in an infinite loop, but it will overrun the end of the buffer until either crash or it finds a space somewhere in random memory.

Comment: @Geoffrey: It sometime crashing does not mean it isn't an infinite loop. And anyway, with harvard-architecture (separate address-space for data), it could even avoid crashing.

Comment: @Geoffrey I know this borders on self-contradiction, but that's the fate of most infinite loops in computer programming : they all eventually finish when the process running them is terminated for one reason or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your using a `char*` and want to find the first blank character in a null terminated string:

```
for (int i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)
    if (str[i] == ' ')
       break;
```

Or you could use the `std::find`.

Answer (score 0):

C++ solution:

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <string>         // std::string

int main() {
    std::string str1("123 56");
    std::string str2 (" ");

    std::size_t found = str1.find(str2);
    if (found!=std::string::npos)
        std::cout << "first ' ' found at: " << found << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
first ' ' found at: 3
```